# Convert bytecode to opcode using web3j

Tags: web3-java, evm

I can't find any documentation on this, is there a converter from bytecode to opcode inside web3j? Or do I need to build one myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for a Java implementation, as it doesn't exist in web3j:

https://github.com/fergarrui/ethereum-disassembler